# Adelic functions of moderate growth

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, adeles

Let $f:GL_2(\mathbb A_\mathbb Q)\to\mathbb C$.
For $g\in GL_2(\mathbb A)$ and a place $v$ of $\mathbb Q$, define $\|g\|_v=\max_{1\le i,j\le 2}(|g_{ij}|_v,|(g^{-1})_{ij}|_v).$
I have seen several definitions for $f$ to be slowing increasing:

Definition 1: For all $x\in GL_2(\mathbb A_f)$, there exists $c,N>0$ such that $|f(xy)|\le C \|y\|_\infty^N$ for all $y\in GL_2(\mathbb R)$. Here $\mathbb A_f$ is the ring of finite adeles.

Definition 2: There exists constant $C,N>0$ such that $|f(g)|\le C(\sup_v \|g\|_v)^N$ for all $g\in GL_2(\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$.

Definition 3: There exists constant $C,N>0$ such that $|f(g)|\le C(\prod_v \|g\|_v)^N$ for all $g\in GL_2(\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$.

These definitions do not seem to be equivalent. If we assume that $f$ satisfies all other conditions for $f$ to be an automorphic form (i.e. left $GL_2(\mathbb Q)$-invariant, right $K$-finiteness, smooth, $Z(\mathfrak g)$-finiteness), then are they equivalent? If not, which one is the correct or more common one?